# WordPress Custom Nav Output

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation, wordpress-theming

I am looking to get a custom WordPress nav output but I'm struggling to understand where to go with it.

At the moment, the default output for WordPress is this:

```
<ul>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link
    <ul><li>Link</li></ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

But what I need to output is the following:

```
<ul>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link
    <ul><div><span></span><li>Link</li><span></span></div></ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Now I know there is the $before and $after in WordPress but unfortunately if you use this it adds it to every link rather than just the child li's that I want it to add them to.

I understand this would be done with using the custom walker method but to say I'm confused is an understatement! Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What are you doing to need these divs and spans that can't be done with setting the CSS for `ul li ul`?

Comment: It's to add a button styling behind each child <li>. It needs the spans in there as well. Can't just be done by editing the <li> CSS.

Answer (score 0):

To modify the output HTML of the Wordpress menu you could use a **[walker](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/Walker_Class)** script.

I'm not able to explain this in a simple way myself, but there are good **[tutorials](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/understanding-the-walker-class/)** out there.

As far as I know the default script that Wordpress uses looks like [this](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L10), and you may with some reading and coding skills be able to create the walker you need from modifying this one with your preferred tags.